# How I create calendar inside Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

How I create Custom Calendar[Like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxwUP.png) inside power Bi and get output based on date selection?

Comment: What's the source of the image? its a relative date slicer, while connected to a cube

Comment: Yes, With specific option there is a custom date selection option is there